# Searching instead of breaking line - EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm making a dictionary. I want when I press "Enter", the EditText doesn't insert new line and do search instead. How to do it?

I tried OnKey, OnKeyDown, OnEditorAction but it doesn't work. When I press "Enter", EditText inserts a new line.

```
public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("OnEditor.");
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
            event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
            event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        System.out.println("OnEditor.");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Update: imeOption doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also restrict edittext to single line using

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the deprecated singleLine attribute you are supposed to use

```
android:inputType="text"
```

to force single line input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) attribute in your XML which will show the appropriate keyboard button. Then you can listen for the onEditorAction call.

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your edit text

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

Comment: using android 2.2, it still breaks line.